# Django orm group_by

Tags: django, django-models, orm, group-by, django-orm

Is there a way to tell Django ORM to ***GROUP BY*** by specific column? Something like this.

`SELECT 
    pk,
    somecol1,
    somecol2
    somecol3
    MIN(somecol2) AS first,
    COUNT(somecol2) AS count
FROM customer
GROUP BY somecol2`

Based on Django ORM documentation, it's possible to do ***GROUP BY***.

Some examples:

`SomeModel.objects.annotate(Count('somecol'))`
GROUP BY: all fields of the model

`SomeModel.objects.values('name').annotate(Count('somecol'))`

GROUP BY: name

`SomeModel.objects.annotate(Count('somecol')).values('name')`
GROUP BY: all cols of the model

`SomeModel.objects.values('name', 'pk').annotate(Count('somecol')).values('pk')`
GROUP BY: name, pk

`SomeModel.objects.values('name').annotate(Count('somecol')).values('pk')`
GROUP BY: name, pk

## WHY is it impossible to choose GROUP BY clause as below examples.

`SomeModel.objects.values('pk', 'somecol1', 'somecol2', 'somecol3').annotate(Count('somecol2'))`

OR

`SomeModel.objects.values('pk', 'somecol1', 'somecol2', 'somecol3').annotate(Count('somecol2')).group_by('somecol2')`

GROUP BY: is_active

Comment: look at the docs for annotations

Answer (score 0):

**Django ORM groupby method**:

**Sql queries**:

```
SELECT
is_active,
COUNT(id) AS count_total
FROM
auth_user
WHERE
is_staff = True
GROUP BY
is_active
```

**Django ORM**

```
from django.db.models import Count,Max,Min,Avg

queryset = (User.objects
.values(
'is_active',
)
.filter(
is_staff=True,
)
.annotate(
total=Count('id'),
)
)
```

**Reference link**:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is yes. Here is the documentation for aggregation, with a handy cheat-sheet:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/

Good luck.

Comment: Django orm groups by customer_id, first_name, last_name whereas I want group_by only by customer_id or whatever field I specify. There is no method such as .group_by('customer_id')

Comment: Couldn't you do something like: SomeModel.objects.values('customer_id').annotate(total_count=count('value')) ?

Comment: This way, it will work fine but I need to select more fields and group by only one specified field.

Comment: @user2413463 django doesn't give you direct access to groupby. It generates the correct groupby based on other fields you're pulling out. Grouping by a random column (especially a non-unique one) is doomed to return incorrect results. Reconsider what you're trying to do I think.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton what do you mean by "_especially a non-unique one_"? If you group by unique column you get 1 for each grouping... because it won't group anything because they are all **unique**. Let's say you want to group by future humans to their planet because we have spread to all of them and we want the population of each of the planets, we group by planet not by person.

Comment: @rain01 grouping by a primary key (or unique column) is syntactically allowed on some backends (mysql, postgres) and is useful in the same situations that grouping by every column is useful (related sets mostly). Most backends will fail if you fail to add a select column to the grouping list (except mysql).

Comment: @JoshSmeaton Ok, what would be the useful case when you need to group by a unique column?